# How to update a specific data but for multiple and specific user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

##### Problem

I need to only update one object from an array of all users who have the object to update

##### Explanation

I have two types of data:

- my soft skills
- my users

some users may have a "soft" table that contains the skills present in the 'my soft skills' data.

When an admin edits the data of a "soft skills" object, I also have to update a user's specific soft skill.

Here `$data` contains the value updated in "soft skills".

I first get the user who has a "soft" array.
Then, I get data from one soft skill.

Then, for each user, I need to update only the skill who have the same common Id from the "one soft skill".

Now, I don't really know how to make the update.

```
public function UpdateOneSkill(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->get('data');
    $department = $data['department'];
    $CommonId = $data['CommonId'];

    if ($department === 'Soft') {
        $users = User::where('skills.soft', 'exists', true)->get();

        $softSkill = SoftSkill::where('CommonId', $CommonId)->first();

        if ($softSkill) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $skills = $user->skills['soft'];

                foreach ($skills as $skill) {
                    if ($skill['CommonId'] == $CommonId) {
                    }
                }

                //ici user->skill save
                $user->save();
            }

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Skills updated successfully.']);
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

```
$skill = array_merge($skill, $softSkill->toArray());
break;

$user->skills['soft'] = $skills;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit the array of skills and then set the updated array back to the skills

```
  public function UpdateOneSkill(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->get('data');
        $department = $data['department'];
        $CommonId = $data['CommonId'];

        if ($department === 'Soft') {

            $users = User::where('skills.soft', 'exists', true)->get();

            $softSkill = SoftSkill::where('CommonId', $CommonId)->first();

            if ($softSkill) {


                foreach ($users as $user) {
                    $skills = $user->skills['soft'];

                    foreach ($skills as &$skill) {
                        if ($skill['CommonId'] == $CommonId) {
                            // Update the specific skill
                            $skill = array_merge($skill, $softSkill->toArray());
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Update the skills array in the user's attribute
                    $user->skills = array_merge($user->skills, ['soft' => $skills]);
                    $user->save();
                }

                return response()->json(['message' => 'Skills updated successfully.']);
            }
        }
    }
```